# Enumerable.SelectMany throws Error CS0411 - cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, ienumerable, yield

I'm using c#, .net 6.0

I'm trying to convert IEnumerable method and ot's caller method to work asynchronously.

I have a code that looks something like that:

```
    public IEnumerable<MyUser> getUsers()
{
    return AccountById
        .Keys
        .SelectMany(accountId => {
            try
            {
                return getUsersFor(accountId)
                    .Select(x => new MyUser(x,
                        SetAccountUniqueName(AccountById[accountId].Name,
                            AccountById[accountId].Id)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error(ex);
                return Enumerable.Empty<MyUser>();
            }
        });
}

public IEnumerable<User> getUsersFor(string accountId)
{
    ListUsersResponse usersResponse;
    string marker = null;
    do
    {
        using (var myClient = new ServiceClient(accountId))
        {
            usersResponse =
                myClient.ListUsersAsync(
                        new ListUsersRequest { Marker = marker, MaxItems = MAX_ITEMS })
                    .Result;
            foreach (var user in usersResponse.Users)
            {
                yield return user;
            }
        }

        marker = usersResponse.Marker;
    } while (usersResponse.IsTruncated);
}
```

I converted getUsers() and getUsersFor() to work asynchronously.

I tried this code:

```
    public async Task<List<MyUser>> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        return await AccountById
            .Keys
            .SelectMany(async accountId =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await foreach (var user in GetUsersForAsync(accountId))
                    {
                        var u = new MyUser(user,
                            SetAccountUniqueName(AccountById[accountId].Name,
                                AccountById[accountId].Id));
                        return u;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error(ex, $"Failed to get account {accountId} users list.");
                    return Enumerable.Empty<MyUser>();
                }
            });
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<User> GetUsersForAsync(string accountId)
    {
        ListUsersResponse usersResponse;
        string marker = null;
        do
        {
            using (var myClient = new ServiceClient(accountId))
            {
                usersResponse =
                    await myClient.ListUsersAsync(
                            new ListUsersRequest { Marker = marker, MaxItems = MAX_ITEMS });
                foreach (var user in usersResponse.Users)
                {
                    yield return user;
                }
            }

            marker = usersResponse.Marker;
        } while (usersResponse.IsTruncated);
    }
```

But I get this error:

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable, Func<TSource, IEnumerable>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: _"cannot be inferred from the usage"_ means that the compiler is unable to determine which type you are returning.   You should try defining it: `.SelectMany<User>(...`?

Comment: What does `AccountById` return?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain `AccountById`  is `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Account>`

Comment: The code in the try block returns a `MyUser` while the code in the catch block retuns an `IEnumerable<MyUser>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use LINQ for asynchronous operations. SelectMany of asynchronous call returns `Task` which is wrong way if you do not await them.

Simple `foreach` will work in your case, don't complicate things.

```cs
public async Task<List<MyUser>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    var result = new List<MyUser>();
    foreach (var accountId in AccountById.Keys)
    {
        try
        {
            await foreach (var user in GetUsersForAsync(accountId))
            {
                var u = new MyUser(user,
                    SetAccountUniqueName(AccountById[accountId].Name,
                        AccountById[accountId].Id));
                result.Add(u);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, $"Failed to get account {accountId} users list.");
        }    
    }

    return result;
}
```